# Custom UIButton in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, button

i want a view with some button, each button must have an image on the left, e bold title and under this, details in italic, is possible make this?

The only (stupid) way i've found is put 2 label over the button, is there any other way?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to have custom positioning of the image and label is to subclass UIButton and override `-titleRectForContentRect:` and `-imageRectForContentRect:`. Of course, UIButtons only have one label by default, so you'll need to add a second label (e.g. in `-initWithFrame:`/`-initWithCoder:`) and lay it out in `-layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass a UIButton and in the `– drawRect:` method, do your custom drawing. You can pretty much draw whatever you like in it.

Answer (score 0):

If the title and details are of dynamic nature you'll have to make your own subclass of UIButton and override the drawRect method.